# puzzled about what's going on behind \b ( backspacing ) in python3

Tags: python, python-3.6, backspace, escaping

I was learning the basics about the escape string \ and stumbled into
\b I was testing things using \b and figured that it
involves cursor moving backward for one spot, and whatever that comes after \b could overwrite. 
However, with such limited knowledge, I
failed to understand
why the above script does not print anything out in the Command Line Interface.
What's going on in behind the code.

```
print("a\b", end='')
print("a\b", end='')
print("a\b", end='')
print("a\b", end='')
```

The code prints out nothing.
I thank you in advance for any precious advice

Comment: Hello! I think it's generally a good idea not to post an image to the code ;) You can actually use the editor to copy/paste your code, so that people won't have to open a link to an image (you know, some people might post stuff not safe).

Also, does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657702/what-do-t-and-b-do

Comment: @Markon Thanks :) for your kind advice. It was my first post for questions. Thnx for precious advice and yes!! the link just explains it !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667462/backspace-behavior-in-python-statement-what-is-correct-behavior-of-printing-a), read:

> he backspace doesn't delete anything, it moves the cursor to the left
>   and it gets covered up by what you write afterwards.

Here you are printing one character, moving the cursor to the left, then printing the empty string `""` on top of it.
To get a clearer idea, try:

```
>>> print("hh\b", end="")
```

The output looks like:

```
h>>>
```

Comment: Thnx for the intuitive answer : )  so does the >>> following right next to the 'h' mean any work afterward would be done in the spot right next to the 'h' ??

Comment: +) as it is only "" empty string that covered the pre-existing 'h'